# how to show a collapsible comments box dynamically in php and mysql using bootstrap within a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Guys i'm trying to create a collapsible comment box in php&mysql using bootstrap i tried some variations but it isn't working as the comments comeup for one post but not for the entire posts. here is a example of my last try, any help would be appriciated.

```
echo $statusui_edit.'<div attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="statusboxes status_'.$updateid.'  jumbotron">'
                        . '<h3 class="pull-left title">'
                        . '<div id="'.$updateid.'" class="title_s_2copy posted" value="'.html_entity_decode($title).'">'.html_entity_decode($title).'</div></h3>'
                        . '<span class="pull-right">'
                        . '<div class="dropdown">'
                        . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  >'
                        . '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>'
                        . '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'
                         .$edit_btn .' '. $statusdeletebutton .'</ul></div></span><br><hr>'
                        . '<legend><span class=" data_s_2copy" type="'.$updateid.'" >'
                        . html_entity_decode($data).'</span></legend><b class="posted"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="home.php?u='.$author.'">'.$author.   '</a>   '.$post_date.'</small></b>'
                        . '<br><legend>'.$like.' | '.$unlike. '</legend>';
echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  comments
</a>';         
// Fetch Comments of update
        $totalComments=$project->totalComments($_SESSION['uname'],$friend,$updateid);   
        foreach($totalComments as $row1){
             $status_reply_id=$row1['comment_id'];
                $reply_d=htmlentities($row1['comment_body']);
                $reply_data=  stripslashes($reply_d);
                $reply_osid=$row1['os_id'];
                $reply_date=$row1['time_c'];
                $reply_author=$row1['author_c'];
                include 'ratings/vote_count4comments.php';
               $like_r='<a  type="like" class="status_liker_'.$status_reply_id.' like_r" attr="'.$status_reply_id.'">Like</a>('.$num_likes_r[0].')';
             $unlike_r='<a  type="unlike" class="status_unliker_'.$status_reply_id.' unlike_r" attr="'.$status_reply_id.'">Unlike</a>('.$num_unlikes_r[0].')';

        if ($reply_author==$_SESSION['uname'] ) {
                   $reply_delete_button='<li><a href="#" type="'.$status_reply_id.'" class="delete_reply_btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_"'.$status_reply_id.'" title="Delete this comment"> Remove</a></span></li>';
               } else{
                   $reply_delete_button="";
               }
               echo '<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                    <div class="well">' ;
          echo  '<div  class="replyboxes pull-left reply_' .$status_reply_id.'">'
                      . 'Reply by:- '
                      . '<a href="home.php?u='.$reply_author. '">'.$reply_author.'</a>'
                      . '<span class="pull-right">'.$reply_date 
                       . '<b class="dropdown">
                         <small><span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown"  >
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></span>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">'.$reply_delete_button
                      . '<li><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" href="report.php?u='.$reply_author.'"> Report</a><li></ul></span>'
                      . '</small></b><br><legend>'.  html_entity_decode($reply_data).'<br>'.$like_r.'|'.$unlike_r.'</legend></div>';
                      echo '</div></div >';     

               } 
        echo '<textarea id="reply_textarea_'.$updateid.'"  class="status_reply_'.$updateid.' input-custom2" placeholder="comment\'s"></textarea>'
                            . '<button id="reply_butn_'.$updateid.'" attr="'.$updateid.'" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm reply_butn reply_'.$updateid.'">Reply</button></div>';

        }
```

**Edited:-**Finally figured out how to collapse content dynamically after some experiments with bootstrap. All i did was, is to add a key to the loop value and insert it to the toggle and call it via javascript(jquery). you can refer here on how i did it.

```
    //fetch update_id from update table in db and inject it to the feed query.
    $totalUpdates=$project->totalUpdates($_SESSION['uname'],$friend);   
    foreach ($totalUpdates as $j=>$row1){
            $updateid=$row1['update_id'];
                $account_name=$row1['account_name'];
                $os_id=$row1['os_id'];
                $author=$row1['author'];
                $post_date=$row1['time'];
                $title= stripslashes($row1['title']);
                $data= stripslashes($row1['update_body']);
                include 'ratings/vote_count.php';
             $like='<a  type="like" class="status_like_'.$updateid.' like" attr="'.$updateid.'">Like</a>('.$num_likes[0].')';
             $unlike='<a  type="unlike" class="status_unlike_'.$updateid.' unlike" attr="'.$updateid.'">Unlike</a>('.$num_unlikes[0].')';

                if ($author==$_SESSION['uname'] || $account_name==$_SESSION['uname']) {
                $statusdeletebutton='<li>'
                           . '<a href="#" type="'.$updateid.'" class="delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_'.$updateid.' glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li>';
                $edit_btn='<li>'
                        . '<a href="#" attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li>';
                $statusui_edit="<div type='".$updateid."' class='hidden_edit_4_session session_editor".$updateid." jumbotron'>"
            . "<a href='#' type='".$updateid."' class='pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a>"
            . "<input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit title_s_".$updateid."' name='status_title' value='".html_entity_decode($title)."' placeholder='Title' >"
            . "<span>&nbsp;</span>"
            . "<textarea id='wall_edit_1' type='".$updateid."' rows='5' cols='50'  class='session_edit text_value_".$updateid."' wrap='hard' placeholder='whats up ".$session_uname."'>
             ".html_entity_decode($data)."</textarea><br>"
            . "<button style='float:right;' value='".$updateid."' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div>" ;

                }else{
                    $statusdeletebutton="";
                    $edit_btn="<li class='posted'>You are not the owner of this Post</li>";
                    $statusui_edit="";
                }

       echo $statusui_edit.'<div attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="statusboxes status_'.$updateid.'  jumbotron">'
                        . '<h3 class="pull-left title">'
                        . '<div id="'.$updateid.'" class="title_s_2copy posted" value="'.html_entity_decode($title).'">'.html_entity_decode($title).'</div></h3>'
                        . '<span class="pull-right">'
                        . '<div class="dropdown">'
                        . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  >'
                        . '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>'
                        . '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'
                         .$edit_btn .' '. $statusdeletebutton .'</ul></div></span><br><hr>'
                        . '<legend><span class=" data_s_2copy" type="'.$updateid.'" >'
                        . html_entity_decode($data).'</span></legend><b class="posted"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="home.php?u='.$author.'">'.$author.   '</a>   '.$post_date.'</small></b>'
                        . '<br><legend>'.$like.' | '.$unlike. '</legend>';
               ?>
<h3><a id="<?php echo $j;?>" class=" collap-btn">Comments</a></h3>
    <!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
  <div id="toggle<?php echo $j;?>" class="collapse">
   <?php
// Fetch Comments of update
        $totalComments=$project->totalComments($_SESSION['uname'],$friend,$updateid);   
        foreach($totalComments as $row1){
             $status_reply_id=$row1['comment_id'];
                $reply_d=htmlentities($row1['comment_body']);
                $reply_data=  stripslashes($reply_d);
                $reply_osid=$row1['os_id'];
                $reply_date=$row1['time_c'];
                $reply_author=$row1['author_c'];
                include 'ratings/vote_count4comments.php';
               $like_r='<a  type="like" class="status_liker_'.$status_reply_id.' like_r" attr="'.$status_reply_id.'">Like</a>('.$num_likes_r[0].')';
             $unlike_r='<a  type="unlike" class="status_unliker_'.$status_reply_id.' unlike_r" attr="'.$status_reply_id.'">Unlike</a>('.$num_unlikes_r[0].')';

        if ($reply_author==$_SESSION['uname'] ) {
                   $reply_delete_button='<li><a href="#" type="'.$status_reply_id.'" class="delete_reply_btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_"'.$status_reply_id.'" title="Delete this comment"> Remove</a></span></li>';
               } else{
                   $reply_delete_button="";
               }
              echo '
                <div  class="replyboxes pull-left reply_' .$status_reply_id.'">'
                      . 'Reply by:- '
                      . '<a href="home.php?u='.$reply_author. '">'.$reply_author.'</a>'
                      . '<span class="pull-right">'.$reply_date 
                       . '<b class="dropdown">
                         <small><span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown"  >
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></span>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">'.$reply_delete_button
                      . '<li><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" href="report.php?u='.$reply_author.'"> Report</a><li></ul></span>'
                      . '</small></b><br><legend>'.  html_entity_decode($reply_data).'<br>'.$like_r.'|'.$unlike_r.'</legend></div>';


               } 
        echo '<textarea id="reply_textarea_'.$updateid.'"  class="status_reply_'.$updateid.' input-custom2" placeholder="comment\'s"></textarea>'
                            . '<button id="reply_butn_'.$updateid.'" attr="'.$updateid.'" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm reply_butn reply_'.$updateid.'">Reply</button></div></div>';

        }
                }
```

the javascript that i used to produce the result is as follows:-

```
$(".collap-btn").click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
        $("#toggle"+id).collapse('toggle');
    });
```